# Monitoring pods on namespace without create a new namespace

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, fluentd

My company has a cluster that's already been monitoring by a datadog agent. But my team needs a monitoring just for us.
I already looked on fluentd, prometheus and so on, but I cound't find an option for use a tool that I don't need to install in my namespace.

Does anyone know an option that I can collect the logs of my pods just in my namespace?
Like, up a pod for grafana and another for collect logs and send to grafana or something like that?

Comment: So do you want to collect metrics or logs? Also: `"but I cound't find an option for use a tool that I don't need to install in my namespace"` - does it mean that you don't want to deploy anything in your namespace? How is that supposed to work? Also, maybe [loki](https://github.com/grafana/loki) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to collect logs. I mean, I want to deploy it in my namespace for only collect logs on it. It should work like: I need deploy something in my namespace to collect logs of my pods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fluentd as a `daemonset` on your cluster.

see this repo and docker images -> [fluent/fluentd-docker-image](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-docker-image)

and use this filter to add [Kubernetes metadata](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter) to every log collected by Fluentd and then use a grep filter to exclude logs that are not in your namespaces.

something like this:

```
# Collect pod logs
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/*fluent*.log"]
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_key time
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>

# add Kubernetes metadata
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
  @id filter_kube_metadata
  kubernetes_url 'https://' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST') + ':' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT') + '/api'
  verify_ssl true
</filter>

# filter and exclude logs that are not in the namespaces `ns1` and `ns2`
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_
    pattern /^(?!(ns1|ns2))/
  </exclude>
</filter>
```

Comment: But, is that possible to deploy it just in my namespace without using nothing in my cluster? I don't have access to the cluster and get the informations to put on Kubernetes metadata. Or can I get this informations just in my namespace?

Comment: Basically, by this solution, you need to have access to the host `/var/log` path to read the log files and be able to call Kubernetes APIs.

You can set up Fluentd to accept logs from HTTP calls and send all logs to it by HTTP call which I think isn't good for you because use lots of networks.

Comment: Also, could you check can you use Fluentd as a sidecar logger beside your pods?

Comment: Well, if I can use it as a sidecar beside my pods just in my namespace would be great. Because as I said before, I don't have access to call the Kubernetes APIs.